# Disable "Tags" prompt in OS 10.9 Save dialog

Tags: finder, macos

In Mavericks, the Save dialog now offers the ability to add Tags to the file you're saving:

[image]

Supposing I want to remove this prompt, likely by running a shell command involving `defaults write com.apple.finder`. How do I do so?

Comment: If it's somewhere it's not in `com.apple.finder.plist`. I didn't found a variable to change that.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't seem to be in that particular file. But it seems like the sort of thing that Apple would expose somewhere.

Comment: Yep I thought that too. I looked also in `.GlobalPreferences.plist`. There is nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing all `.plist` files in `~/Library/preferences`. I don't find any options that would match your request.

If you want to try it yourself, here are the commands I used :

Convert all `plist` to xml text files (because some of them (are|can be) binary files)  :
`find . -name "*.plist" -exec plutil -convert xml1 "{}" \;`

search the files for `tag`: 
`grep -rie "<key>.*tag.*</key>" .`

Comment: Well, that certainly makes it sound likely that it can't be disabled. I'll mark your answer as correct until someone proves otherwise.